# Constant header in spring mvc jsp though with session specific elements (like user profile details etc)

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, header

In my Spring mvc jsp..(lets call it home page) for logged in user, I have a header and left nav bar which contains user specific elements (image, last logged in, nav menu based on permissions etc)
As the user navigates to each additional view I am currently feeding the user back an entirely new jsp with all the same content for header and left nav menu.
Can someone please help me understand how i can avoid this (if possible) because as far as logged in user is concerned header and left menu is static and need not keep updating for each view.

1. I have heard about Apache Tiles though am not sure if that is the solution. Can i try to make a main content 'tile' and have only this refreshed?
2. I had tried using Ajax with which I was able to 'rewrite' the div content for my main content portion of the page.. but i hit a roadblock in trying to get the javascript for the next view also rewritten or rather 'overwritten' over existing js on the main page. (append to  will not work since I am using similar named functions on different views eg function get_details(){}.  this is pretty much on every jsp but with slightly different functionality. so i cant append unless im pretty sure submit and button clicks etc will call the correct js functions).

Comment: Tiles would be the best choice in here.

Comment: @Jayaraj - but i just read somewhere that all the tiles need to be refreshed on page display and not only selective ones.. is this correct? if so, it doesn't help me reduce to and fro data transfer for the header portion